# Mutable Vector field is not updating in F#

Tags: f#, linear-regression, gradient-descent

```
let gradientDescent (X : Matrix<double>) (y :Vector<double>) (theta : Vector<double>) alpha (num_iters : int) =
    let J_history = Vector<double>.Build.Dense(num_iters)
    let m = y.Count |> double
    theta.At(0, 0.0)
    let x =  (X.Column(0).PointwiseMultiply(X*theta-y)) |> Vector.sum
    for i in 0 .. (num_iters-1) do
        let next_theta0 = theta.[0] - (alpha / m) * ((X.Column(0).PointwiseMultiply(X*theta-y)) |> Vector.sum)
        let next_theta1 = theta.[1] - (alpha / m) * ((X.Column(1).PointwiseMultiply(X*theta-y)) |> Vector.sum)
        theta.[0] = next_theta0 |> ignore
        theta.[1] = next_theta1 |> ignore
        J_history.[i] = computeCost X y theta |> ignore
        ()
    (theta, J_history)
```

> Even though matrices and vectors are mutable, their dimension is fixed
> and cannot be changed after creation.
>
> http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html

I have theta which is a vector of size 2x1
I'm trying to update theta.[0] and theta.[1] iteratively but when I look at it after each iteration it remains to be [0;0]. I know that F# is immutable but I quoted above from their website that Vectors and Matrix are mutable so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

**My hunch is that it has something to do with Shadowing... because I'm declaring a let next_theta0 in a for loop but I'm not too sure**

Also, as a follow up question. I feel like the way I implemented this is incredibly terrible. There's literally no reason for me to have implemented this in F# when it would have been much easier in C# (using this methodology) because it doesn't feel very "functional" Could anyone suggest ways to approve on this to make it more functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructive update operator in F# is written `<-`, so:

```
theta.[0] <- next_theta0
```

What you're doing in your code is *comparing* `theta.[0]` with `next_theta0`, which is an operation that results in a `bool`, which is why you had to add an `ignore` call after it, to avoid the compiler warning.

Here's a good general rule: when you see a compiler warning, don't just try tricks to appease the compiler. Instead, try to understand why the warning appears. Chances are, it points to a legitimate problem.

And here's a more F#-specific rule: using `ignore` is a code smell. `ignore` is a sort of hack, mostly used for interaction with external code, when the external code returns something, but doesn't really expect the consumer to use that return value.

Comment: Ahh, yes I had read about that and completely forgotten it. I was wondering why it was returning a bool.... thanks!